# How can I make my rapier more powerful?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons

We're playing a campaign at level 6 and I have a *+1 moontouched flametouched silvered rapier* and 19 dexterity.

Is there any way to make it more likely to hit or do more damage? I want to improve it as I know how easy it is to miss, having an AC of 23 myself.

---

**Moontouched:** glows out to 60'

**Flametouched:** +1 fire damage

Comment: What armour do you wear? And do you wield a shield?

Comment: I've joined the reopen voting as "clear enough." If OP wants to bump up hit probability and/or damage, there's a relatively straightforward finite list of ways to achieve this. But if others feel it's too broad, vote your conscience. I'll not override a community vote.

Comment: What class is your character? Fighter? Rogue? Barbarian?  Bard?  Wizard? Warlock?

Comment: How do you have AC23? Are you not miscalculating something?

Answer (score 14):

> Is there any way to make it more likely to hit or do more damage?

There are a **lot** of ways to make it more likely to hit or do more damage. Here's a brief overview. This isn't intended to be an exhaustive list of all the options you've got, but it is intended to be an exhaustive list of all the *categories* of options you've got.

#### Improve your attack roll

Gain advantage, halfling luck (you didn't mention your race?), portent dice, precision dice, bardic inspiration, a *bless* spell, and many, many others.

#### Improve your attack bonus

Improve your Dex by mundane or magical means, improve your proficiency bonus by leveling up, or improve the bonus on your weapon--probably by finding a new one.

#### Improve your damage roll

Sneak attack, smites, hunter's mark, hex, brutal critical, expanded critical, savage attacker, various battle master maneuvers, and many others.

#### Improve your damage bonus

Improve your Dex by mundane or magical means, rage (though depending on your str-dex differential that may not actually help), improve the bonus on your weapon.

### But most of all, improve your communication

Given that you're at level 6 and have a *moontouched flametouched silvered rapier +1* and somehow you've got an AC of 23<sup>*</sup>, I'm going to go out on a limb and either say that your game features plenty of homebrew or just *lots* of magic. Both of which are fine, but both of which are heavily dependent on your GM's largesse.

They're the one you should be asking this--for all we know there's a *+3 bracelet of hitting more with rapiers* lying around somewhere, just waiting for you to quest for it.

---

<sup>* - To get up to an AC of 23 there's got to be quite a bit going on. If you're lightly armored you've got something like 12 (studded leather) + 4 (dex of 19) + 2 (shield, I suppose?) and we need to find 5 more AC points from... magic items? Enchantments to the armor and shield? Fighting style (+1 max)?</sup>

<sup>Or your medium-armored: 15 (half plate) + 2 (dex, capped), +2 (shield) leaves you needing 4 more AC points....</sup>

<sup>Or you're heavily armored: 18 (plate) + 2 (shield) leaves you needing 3 more AC points.</sup>

<sup>Or you've got a class feature that allows you to add another stat to AC? But those features come with limitations on armor, still leaving you a shortfall.</sup>

<sup>What's my point? There're clearly a bunch of magical items bumping up your AC. Which brings us back to the earlier point about GM largesse. You seem to be in a Monty Haul campaign, so just talk to your GM and try to steer the flavor of the hoards you're running across.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of possibilities.

Adding another point of Dex would help a bit -- +1 to hit and damage.

If you have (or can add) a class with a Fighting Style, adding Duelling will give an additional -- +2 to damage.

Any class that has a spell that adds to melee damage (Hex, Hunters Mark, Divine Favor) will help -- +1d6 or 1d4 to damage.

Taking levels in Rogue can give you Sneak Attack dice added, up to once per turn -- +1d6 to damage at first level, going up from there with more levels.

Taking a level in War Cleric will give you an additional bonus action attack a few times per long rest.

Taking the Champion Fighter archetype gives you improved critical hits -- natural 19 or 20 instead of just 20.

Taking the Battle Master Fighter archetype gives you superiority dice you can add to damage in several ways, or to accuracy with Precision Attack -- +1d8 a few times per short rest.

Adding Paladin can give you Divine (and other) Smite(s) -- Spend spell slots for additional damage.

Nearly all of these things are additive; you can do all of them, except take both the two fighter archetypes.